# why won't bash display the results of a 'bind -p' command?

Tags: bash, bind, zsh

bash refuses to give me the output of 'bind -p' when I pass it in with the -c switch:

```
bash -c 'bind -p'
```

but it works to type

```
bind -p
```

directly  at the bash prompt, and it works to type something like

```
bash -c 'echo "hi"'
```

and zsh happily does exactly what bash refuses to do (well, the equivalent command in zsh):

```
zsh -c 'bindkey -L'
```

What on earth is going on???

Comment: (If you're wondering why I need to pass 'bind -p' to bash rather than just typing it at the command line, it's because I'm using a system call from a Ruby program.)

Comment: `bash -c 'bind -p'` works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `bash` with the `-c` option, `bash` runs in non-interactive mode. Apparently, the `bind` builtin doesn't generate output when bash is in non-interactive mode. You can force `bash` to interactive mode by giving the `-i` option. The following works for me:

```
bash -i -c 'bind -p'
```

Comment: ok, for bonus points, can you explain why you and I are having it work this way, but Dennis Williamson is not?

Comment: @Brandon: I would need to know more about his shell environment to even begin to hazard a guess.

Comment: @Brandon: Probably a version issue. `bind -c 'bind -p'` gives no output for me with Bash 3.2.39, but produces the same output as with `-i` or `set -o emacs` with Bash 4.1.15. Without `-i` or `set -o`, Bash 4 additionally emits `bash: line 0: bind: warning: line editing not enabled` on stderr.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have a *partial* answer that I just discovered after entering my question...

If I type

```
bash -c "set -o emacs && bind -p"
```

then it gives the output of the bind command.  It seems that for some reason bash doesn't have a default key map, which is really odd.

(I had had something sourced by my .bash_profile which had an error--something that worked fine in zsh but which bash choked on (apparently bash doesn't allow using 'else' in scripts!?)--and so I just disabled it, figuring default settings would be cleaner anyway.)

It's almost unthinkable that bash doesn't default to either a vi or an emacs keymap.  Or is there something else going on that is escaping me?

Comment: Bash does allow `else` in scripts.

Comment: OOOOOOPS!  I mis-read that as "Bash doesn't allow else in scripts", hence my (previous) comment that that is weird.

Comment: `set -o emacs` has the disadvantage of possibly conflicting with `set editing-mode vi` in the user's `~/.inputrc`.

Comment: @Gilles: would the conflict cause the set -o emacs to fail?

Comment: No, but it means that the resulting information will not describe an interactive instance of bash started without `--norc`. Depending on what you're using the information for, this may be a good or a bad thing.